# why semicolon must be added in the scene of the `yield`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I wrote a demo below to demonstrate the question.

I expect the Generator iterates for the variable `a`, however, the redundant codes after impact it.

Can anyone make it clear step by step why this happens?

**My code is:**

```
function* foo(){
    var a = 0, c
    while(a < 10){
        a += 1
        yield a //if the semicolon is added here, the final result is 1
        [c] = [101]

    }
}

var gen= foo()
console.log(gen.next().value) // [101]
```

Comment: Adding the semicolon will terminate that statement. Without the semicolon Javascript executes the line below so it yields a[c] = [101]

Comment: This is why you should get into the habit of ending every statement in JS with a semicolon.

Comment: ...which is one of the reasons to write your own semicolons, rather than relying on the built-in error-correction mechanism (automatic semicolon insertion) to do it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add a semicolon, the code is actually `yield a; [c] = [101];`

So you `yield` the `a` and the `[c] = [101];` block will not affect the actual returned value.

Otherwise, the code is `yield a[c] = [101];` which is `[101]`:

```js
function* foo(){
    var a = 0, c
    while(a < 10){
        a += 1
        yield a[c] = [101];

    }
}

var gen= foo()
console.log(gen.next().value) // [101]
```

Comment: *"...and the [c] = [101]; block is actually ignored"* Only if the redundant store is optimized away. `[c] = [101]` is a valid statement (not "block"), it's an obtuse way to write `c = 101`. The only reason it would be ignored is if the JavaScript engine noted that `c` is never used.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder isn't the `yield` will cause an actual skip of that statement?

Comment: @Dekel, not if you call the function again.

Comment: @Dekel: Well, it'll happen as many times as that statement is reached; the code just doesn't run the generator to completion. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/2yj215jz/2/

Comment: It will be called 1 less, than the amount of times you call it.  It's kind of the whole point of generators, it will continue were it left off on the next `next`..

Comment: yes, I checked with 2 calls, that was the confusion.